# with file.open('r',encoding="utf-8") as f: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, automation, python-requests

I am trying to extract data from some xml files , I have several directories, in each directory there is many files.
The files have the same names, but different data in each folder.

Ex : 
Folder >> English have file called new.xml
Folder >> Arabic have file called new.xml

I need to hack to new and take some data from it. I am getting this error.

This is my code, what am I doing wrong ?

```
import pathlib
import lxml.etree as etree
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
import functools
import operator

# Extract the name
cwd = pathlib.Path.cwd()
dirs = list(filter(lambda d: d.is_dir(), cwd.iterdir()))
langs = [dir_.name for dir_ in dirs]
files = map(operator.methodcaller('glob', '*.xml'), dirs)
files = map(lambda d: list(map(lambda f: f.with_suffix('').with_suffix('').name, d)), files)
filenames = set(functools.reduce(operator.add, files))

#print(langs)
#print(filenames)

# I will add the names of the files to the identifiers
identifiers = dict()

for file in filenames:
    with file.open('r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        tree = etree.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    identifiers[filename] = root
    print(list(root.tag))
```

Comment: Try with  `with open(file, 'r',encoding="utf-8")` instead of `with file.open('r',encoding="utf-8")` -- like the error says, your `file` is a string containing your file-path not an actual "file object"

Comment: Why are you using pathlib, but then this complicated variety of maps and filters?

Comment: @voiDnyx I tried this already, It is giving me error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HERE_SOME_FILE_NAME' .. Although this file exists in all the directories, not really sure what is wrong now –

Comment: @blueteeth pathlib is quite nice to use and i didnt have any problem with it before.

Comment: Can you show the actual folder structure, and I'll write a solution using pathlib.

Comment: @blueteeth https://imgur.com/BxQzJn6
Inside of each folder there are several files. they have the same name, but different data.

Comment: And all of those directories contain `new.xml`?

Comment: @blueteeth yes, several other files also , but they all have the same names.
new.xml, old.xml, fruits.xml, etc 
Inside each file of those, there are data.
I just need to extract these data (Cdata, Identifiers, subchildren, etc.) Basically I am Planning to take them and write them in another files with different structure, ordering, etc.

Comment: @blueteeth But I cant use with_suffix() and append it to the xml_paths, because basically the files are names " new.abc.xml " and I need only to extract new.xml so that's why in the original code I was using with_suffix twice, What do you think I can do about that? Thanks and sorry for any confusion –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, there are some number of directories, all containing xml files. So the structure is like this:

```
parent1/
  file1.xml
  file2.xml
parent2/
  file1.xml
  ...
```

Here's a solution just using pathlib.

```
import pathlib
import lxml.etree as etree
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

# Extract the name
cwd = pathlib.Path.cwd()
xml_paths = []
for directory in cwd.iterdir():
    if directory.is_file():
        continue
    for path in directory.iterdir():
        if path.suffix == '.xml':
            xml_paths.append(path)


# I will add the names of the files to the identifiers
identifiers = {}

for xml_path in xml_paths:
    with xml_path.open('r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        tree = etree.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()
    identifier = f'{xml_path.parent.name}/{xml_path.name}'
    identifiers[identifier] = root
    print(f'{identifier}:')
    print(list(root.tag))
    print()
```

Comment: But I cant use with_suffix() and append it to the xml_paths, because basically the files are names " new.abc.xml " and I need only to extract new.xml so that's why in the original code I was using with_suffix twice, What do you think I can do about that? Thanks and sorry for any confusion

Comment: I tried "         if path.suffix == '.xml':
            xml_paths.append(path.with_suffix('').name) "

Comment: If you change the path, it's not longer going to be a valid file. The way I've written it gets all the xml files in all the directories you have.  If you want to rename the files, that's a different issue, but I'm not sure why you would. When you're extracting the data, you could set the indentifier to something else.

Comment: You have the file `foo/bar.abc.xml`. If you save `foo/bar.xml`, that's not a valid file. Also `path.with_suffix('').name` is the same as `path.stem`.

Comment: Because the names of the files : new.abc.xml
The identifier in the new files will be named "new" only. without abc, that's why I did with_suffix twice in the old script

Comment: I understand, but you're doing it in the wrong place. `xml_paths` is for a list of existing paths on your computer. If you write the wrong paths there, they aren't going to magically exist. What should the identifier be? It can't just be `new` because presumably multiple files will be called that.

Comment: yes you are right, I found my mistake now and I was able to change it.
Thanks again:))

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the variable file has a string type. The error indicates that you are trying to call the open function on a string object.
You need to use the following code.

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
```

Comment: I tried this already, It is giving me error 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HERE_SOME_FILE_NAME' .. 


Although this file exists in all the directories, not really sure what is wrong now

Answer (score 0):

According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the open function get the following flags:
as @Anton Dikarev mention.

> open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None,
>   newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)

If you are getting the "No such file or directory" it means that you are trying to open the incorrect file path.
you can try to validate if the file is there or not by using (it will return *True* if the file exists or *False* otherwise)

```
import os
os.path.isfile(filename)
```

P.S

If you are still having a problem there is a posibility that are building the *filenames* set wrong, with the incorrect expected file paths.